# Why is a session being saved to my database for every server request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, session

I have an express app that uses express-session and connect-mongodb-store for user sessions. the setp is working correctly when users sign in, their passport gets saved to the database and they stay logged in. However, it seems that my database is being filled with many sessions that have no passport. In testing it I've noticed that a session is created for almost every server request.

Heres the server code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");
const flash = require("express-flash");
var session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const initializePassport = require(__dirname+"/passport-config.js");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const PORT=process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));
initializePassport(passport);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
  },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoDBStore({
      uri: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
      collection: "sessions",
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
    }),
  })
);

app.use(flash());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
  user=req.user;
  next();
})
//routes
...
///
mongoose.connection.once("open", () => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
  });
});

mongoose.connection.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error("MongoDB connection error:", err);
});
```

Heres the data being saved on user sign in:

```
{"_id":"RaJ_m6eXHCD4favlq6E15tljWv-OiCjc","expires":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1691015547496"}},"session":{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"secure":null,"httpOnly":true,"domain":null,"path":"/","sameSite":null},"flash":{},"passport":{"user":"646ef8adfa61e6eac440db91"}}}
```

And the many other sessions being created for requests:

```
{"_id":"QvqtxeS1UCQPy9v-xsCThbqM8XPC5o4q","expires":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1691015549321"}},"session":{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"secure":null,"httpOnly":true,"domain":null,"path":"/","sameSite":null},"flash":{}}}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

I've tried moving app.use(express.static("public")); initializePassport(passport); around but didn't seem to help. I've also tried this to check if a session existed before adding a new session:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoDBStore({
    uri: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
    collection: "sessions",
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
  }),
  // Check if a session already exists before creating a new one
  // This avoids storing a session on every page load
  genid: function (req) {
    return req.sessionID || null;
  }
}));
```

However, users passport info was not saved then and it was impossible to sign in

edit:
Heres the passport-config as well

```
    const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
    const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
    const db=require(__dirname+"/db.js");
    
    function initialize(passport){
        const authenticateUser = async (username,password,done) =>{
            const user = await db.findUserByUsername(username.toLowerCase());
            if(user==null){
                return done(null, false, {message: "No user with that username"})
            }
    
            try{
                if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)){
                    return done(null, user)
                } else{
                    return done(null, false, {message: "password incorrect"})
                }
            } catch (e){
                return done(e)
            }
        }
    
        passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: "username"},authenticateUser));
        passport.serializeUser((user, done) =>  done(null, user.id))
        passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => { 
            const user=await db.findUserByID(id)
            done(null, user);
         })
    }
    
    module.exports = initialize;
```

Comment: that's a lot of `require`s in your index file... it might be time for a refactor.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

try this code it will expire session after a week automatically.
and here is some reference code for you

```
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);

const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
  collection: 'sessions',
  mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
  expires: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
});
    store.on('error', function (error) {
  console.error('MongoDB Session Store Error:', error);
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'your-secret-key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // The same value as the TTL (e.g., 7 days)
    },
  })
);
```